# Возможно ли как-то постоянно хранить переменные в PHP-скрипте без базы данных?

Tags: php, сервер

Есть скрипт небольшого сервера, который распределяет данные между клиентами. Скрипт работает с параметрами `set_time_limit(0);` и `ignore_user_abort(true);`. В этом скрипте есть массив $Clients, структура - `Array('ClientName'=>'...', 'ClientData'=>'...')`. Проблема в том, что при обращении к скрипту каждого клиента, массив создаётся заново, а должен быть наполнен информацией о других клиентах, которые обращались к скрипту. Запросы к скрипту идут постоянно AJAX-ом от каждого авторизовавшегося клиента с некоторым интервалом (от 2 до 4 секунд) и, соответственно, информация в массиве должна обновляться.

Учитывая объём, количество и частоту сообщений, использовать базу данных крайне не эффективно, так как важна скорость работы, тем более база и так нагружена другим функционалом.
В связи с этим прошу совета, как можно хранить в скрипте постоянный массив(ы), который бы не пересоздавался при каждом клиентском обращении?

Comment: Непонятно зачем вам каждые 2-4сек получать список данных по всем клиентам для каждого клиента? У вас на сервере данные клиентов меняются с такой частотой?

Comment: Да, меняются. Представитель 1-го типа клиентов "пингует" сервер с целью проверить не интересуется ли им кто-то из представителей 2-го типа клиентов... Если да - клиент 1-го типа начинает пересылку данных, если "интерес" пропадает (клиент 2-го типа посылает пустую строку), то пересылка данных прекращается. Клиентов 2-го типа будет, ну, может до 10 штук максимум, а 1-го - от 20 до 50. И всех их надо связать корректной маршрутизацией. Но ворпос уже решил по типу сессий - по файлу на каждого

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать [APC](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.apc-store.php), можно скидывать в файл с теми же `json_encode`/`json_decode` (по идее, при частых чтении-перезаписи он всё равно будет браться из кеша файловой системы), можно вообще посмотреть в сторону, например, Node.JS вместо PHP.

Comment: Понятно, пока json наиболее приемлемый вариант... Хотя непонятно как себя поведёт файл при одновременном запросе на запись от двух клиентов... Может есть способ получить все сессии сервера, чтобы запросить данные у конкретного клиента, и обойтись без этого скрипта вообще?

Comment: @Iceman, если данные добавляются, а не изменяются, можно выделить под них отдельную папку и хранить по файлу на клиента. По идее, сессии хранятся подобным образом (путь можно узнать через `ini_get( 'session.save_path')`), хотя они, скорее всего, будут находиться на [особом разделе, специально заточенном для кучи маленьких файлов](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-save-path.php) — возможно, лучше и в самом деле использовать их.

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас основная информация о клиентах находится в базе, чтобы не придумывать дополнительный велосипед, можете попробовать хранить информацию о логах клиентов в таблице с типом [MEMORY](https://habrahabr.ru/post/108457/). В отличие от обычных таблиц, данные хранятся не на диске, а в оперативной памяти, и доступ к ним (чтение/запись) осуществляется очень быстро. По сути вы работаете с оперативкой. Это самое быстрое решение.

Другой вариант, это, как писали выше, использовать инструменты для кеширования - APC, memcached. Но они также, как и MEMORY, работают с оперативкой.

Comment: MEMORY подошло бы, если не максимальная длина строки 64 кб. У клиента может быть запрошен видеопоток с веб-камеры, а там один кадр 250 кб. в разрешении 400х300. Кажется придётся писать на Node.js... или на C++